# PostgreSQL get max limit of all data types through a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can I get the data types and their max limits like mentioned below without storing the limits in a table manually?

```
data-type | limit
integer   |  2147483647
bigint    |  9223372036854775807
```

Comment: No, not possible

Comment: Recursive CTE... which is a really bad idea.